# Zend Form: How to set the length of a text input or textarea element?

Tags: zend-form

By default Zend Form Text elements don't have a width specified. Textarea elements have a default of `rows="24"` and `cols="80"`. But when I set a different value...

```
$body = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('body');
$body->setLabel('Body:')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->setAttrib('COLS', '40')
    ->setAttrib('ROWS', '4');
$this->addElement($body);
```

...the attributes are only added, not changed:

```
<textarea name="body" id="body" COLS="40" ROWS="4" rows="24" cols="80">
```

What is the correct way to specify a width and height of a textarea element, and the column width of a text element?

### Solution:

Apparently, you can't specify html attributes in capital letters or else it will add duplicate attributes.

To change the height and width of a text area element:

```
$textarea = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('body');
$textarea
    ->setAttrib('cols', '40')
    ->setAttrib('rows', '4');
```

To change the width of a text element:

```
$text = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('subject');
$text->setAttrib('size', '40');
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It'll work if you take those attribute names and lowercase'em.

Comment: Returning to this five years later, uppercase now works too.  Progress!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

$text = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('subject');

$text ->setAttrib('maxlength','100');

Answer (score 4):

Using the setAttrib will not affect the stringlength as that attribute is only recognised by text inputs. Try using a validator to control the string length. Note you can also set custom error messages.

```
$text = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea( 'body' );
        $text->      ->setLabel('Body:')
                     ->setAttrib('cols', 50)
                     ->setAttrib('rows', 4)
                     ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(40, 250))
                     ->setRequired( true )
                     ->setErrorMessages(array('Text must be between 40 and 250 characters'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but have you tried using lowercase attribute names? It's pretty tacky but if it works it suggests the language is broken in this respect.

Comment: Not tacky. It's according to specification.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is good practice to add your form attributes in your fieldset class (or form class depending on how you have set it up).

Here is an example:

```
class SomeFieldSet extends Fieldset
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     * @param SomeEntity $claimPrototype
     * @param null $name
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManager $objectManager,
        SomeEntity $somePrototype,
        $name = null,
        $options = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($objectManager));
        $this->setObject($somePrototype);

    }

    public function init()
    {

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'description',
                'type'       => 'textarea',
                'options'    => [
                    'label' => 'Some Label',
                    'instructions' => 'Some instruction',
                ],
                'attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Some placeholder',
                    'required' => 'required',
                    'rows' => 10
                ],
            ]
        );

}
```