# maxlengh attribute in zend form element

Tags: php, zend-form-element

How to handle the lengh of a form input in ZEND framework?

I would like to have a max of 4 characters in my zend form element

Comment: ahhh me eyes! wish I could edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948631/zend-form-how-to-set-the-length-of-a-text-input-or-textarea-element)
Try this for size :

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('test')
$element->setAttrib('size', '4');
```

You may want to have a look at the ZF "Creating Form Elements Using Zend_Form_Element" documentation too : [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html)